# Is it possible to validate @RequestParam in Spring MVC REST endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In Jersey 2 it is possible to do this:

```
@GET
@PATH("user/{email}")
public IDto getUser(@NotNull @Email @PathParam("email") String validEmail) {
    return userManagementService.findUserByEmail(validEmail);
}
```

But I cannot make something similar to work in Spring MVC, it seems that the validation is only done when providing an object in @RequestBody or using an SpringMVC Form, for example the following won't work:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody IDto getUser(@NotNull @Email @PathVariable String validEmail) {
    return userManagementService.findUserByEmail(validEmail);
}
```

There are other similar questions, but those seem to be oriented to Spring MVC UI applications, in my case it is only a REST API which returns JSON response so I don't have any View to map/bind to the controller.

Comment: You minimally need to annotate with `@Valid`, though this might only work if you have a model class and not just a `String`.

Comment: Yes, the question is about simple parameters not about POJO objects as input, for that I know about the @Valid annotation that will use the bean validation from the annotations in the class. But that is not the feature I am asking for

Answer (score 9):

Seems it is possible, using `@Validated`.

Here's an [example](https://sdqali.in/blog/2015/12/04/validating-requestparams-and-pathvariables-in-spring-mvc/).

Based on OP's question, this should work:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class MyController {

  @GetMapping(value="/user/{email}")
  public @ResponseBody IDto getUser(@NotNull @Email @PathVariable String validEmail) {
    return userManagementService.findUserByEmail(validEmail);
  }
 
}
```

In plain Spring implementations, it may be required to manually register the validator bean:

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

Comment: In addition to the link, can you please add a snippet so it is easier to understand the answer even if the link gets broken?

Comment: Adding `@Validated` to the required controller class or method is enough to trigger the validation.

Comment: In my case Is not working by default with @Validated annotation.

Comment: In plain Spring implementations, it may be required to register the validator bean.

Answer (score 5):

1. Simply add `@Validated` annotation at the top of your class.
2. Put whatever annotations for validations (`@NotBlank`, `@Min(1)`, etc.) before the `@RequestParam` annotation in your method signature.

Comment: "Put whatever annotations for validations ([…]) before the @RequestParam annotation in your method signature." — I just tested this, and it doesn't cause it to be validated.  It would surprise me a great deal to learn that the framework cared the order in which these annotations were applied to the method parameter.

Comment: Actually, now that I reread it: were those supposed to be "do 1 or 2" or "do both"?

Comment: @M.Justin It's both.

Answer (score 2):

Controller should be annotated with spring's `@Validated`

So update your code with

```
@Validated
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody IDto getUser(
    @NotNull 
    @Email 
    @PathVariable String validEmail) {
    return userManagementService.findUserByEmail(validEmail);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The validated annotation from the `org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated` package to validate a `@PathVariable`. Make sure the class annotated with `@Validated`.

```
@GetMapping("/name-for-day/{dayOfWeek}")
  public String getNameOfDay(@PathVariable("dayOfWeek") @Min(1) @Max(7) Integer dayOfWeek) {
        return dayOfWeek + "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you cannot do this out-of-the-box with Spring.

Options:

1. Use a regular expression:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value="/user/{email:SOME_REXEXP}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public @ResponseBody IDto getUser(@PathVariable String validEmail) {
       return userManagementService.findUserByEmail(validEmail);
   }
   ```
2. Use Hibernate Validator to validate the method. Either call the validator manually, or make Spring call it for you using AOP. See https://github.com/gunnarmorling/methodvalidation-integration