# Allowed values for RequestParam in get url

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Is it possible to set possible values for     `@RequestParam(value = "id")  String id)`
?

The ideal is: I give some `List<String> allowedValues` and it automatically validate it. (This list will be loaded from database).

Answer (score 2):

use an enum instead of a String and define your enum values

```
@RequestMapping(value = "yourRestEndPoint", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public anyReturnType methodName(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "ONE") IdValue id) {
 ....
}
```

and have a separate class defined e.g

```
public enum IdValue {
  ONE, TWO, THREE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but not some magical way but by simple Validation checks.

**Eg:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "yourRestEndPoint", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public anyReturnType methodName(@RequestParam(value = "id") String id){

     List<String> allowedValues = getAllowedValuesFromDB();

     if(allowedValues.contains(id)){//check if incoming ID belongs to Allowed Values
     //Do your action....
     }
}

private List<String> getAllowedValuesFromDB(){

    List<String> allowedValues = new ArrayList<>();
    //fetch list from DB
    //set fetched values to above List

    return allowedValues;
}
```

**Second Way**

If you want to do it like we do *Bean Validation*, using **@Valid**, which is for Bean not just a single parameter and also required Validator to be configured, then check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24894851/2736849) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37426686/2736849) answer.

Hope this helps.